MSBuild incompatible with GIT: Error LNK1103
I was forced to swithch to Windows and Visual Studio.
I'm completely shocked that the VS is like 20 years ago.
Slow and mostly unable to recover from its ownd problems.
After a git pull, I need to drop everything (something like find | grep x64$ | xargs rm -rf) in order to compile the code.
If I skip this step, I have plenty of LNK1103 "debugging information corrupt; recompile module" - like it is unable to detect, that the sources have changed and doesn't compile required stuff?
